# Open another page after logging in using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver to open a page in my website using python.

The page link is : `"www.example.com/App/Details.aspx/I=5aM%+8KbCv1o=&T=M30Lr7RtcdR=&H=fRFKse5fKA=="`

Since I cannot open this page directly, I have to first login on 
**www.example.com**, which I am doing this way:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
try:
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.get('http://www.example.com')   
except Exception:
    print ('time out')
    #driver.find_element_by_id("Default").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL +'Escape')

username = driver.find_element_by_id("usrid")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("pswd")


username.send_keys("Sample_user")
password.send_keys("samplepass")

driver.find_element_by_id("submitbtn").click()
```

After this I am am able to log in successfully,
but when I redirect to the above link using

```
driver.get("www.example.com/App/Details.aspx/I=5aM%+8KbCv1o=&T=M30Lr7RtcdR=&H=fRFKse5fKA==")
```

I get error saying please login first. Please suggest a solution for the same.

Comment: Why don't you try to _Automate_ just the _Manual Steps_ instead of directly invoking a pre-compiled `url`?

Answer (score 0):

You sent the data via

```
password.send_keys
```

but after that you were to also send enter command using

```
password.send_keys((Keys.ENTER)
```

After this you have to have a

```
sleep(1)
```

or

```
WebDriverWait Until(expect...
```

before you open the next page